# Digitizing excel forms to HTML forms

Tags: javascript, html, css

At work we have a bunch of checklists in excel that we print out to follow certain procedures for certain tasks. Given the current work from home situation, the department is looking at digital solutions.

Making some digital checklists in excel was a nightmare, so I made them using some HTML, CSS and some JS and had quite a bit of success with it, its pretty convenient and does what we need.

As of now, once done with a checklist we 'print' it as pdf and save it. Since this is a security sensitive work environment I have this running completely offline (although on web browsers obviously) This is all good and fine, but I have 2 issues:

**1)** Data is deleted on refresh or closing/reopening page. Temporarily I have used

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

to make sure users don't accidentally lose their work, is there a better solution? I cannot use a server. I am currently looking into how I can save this as a cookie, is this the best way?

**2)** The second issue is 'saving' these checklists for future editing, say halfway through a task and you need to pick something else up. Is there a way to 'save' the data to say csv and then read it back up again?

This second issue is the bigger problem, and I am not sure how to approach it, general googling around hasn't been too helpful as most solutions involve having a server. Only looking for a general point in the right direction on what I can try rather than for someone to write the code for me or anything. We use Chrome and Edge at work if that is helpful at all!

Answer (score 0):

> Data is deleted on refresh or closing/reopening page
>
> I can save this as a cookie, is this the best way?

No, cookies are not really meant for this, I suggest using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)

> The second issue is 'saving' these checklists for future editing

If you want to save it to a file in an editable format you could save it as json and load it in when you want to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage or IndexedDB. But please note that localStorage has a maximum 5MB of storage capacity.
You can also try the cache api 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache